# How to respond to 'Please call when you have a chance'

Tags: communication

I have sent a follow-up email (e.g., great pleasure to meet you, see you soon, etc.) after a business conference to a senior colleague. He responded with 'Dear X., Please call when you have a chance, here is my number:...' He didn't mention any specific time.
Should I call him anytime during the working hours? Or ask for a preferred time? Or did he mention this just casually, nothing serious and no need to call?

Answer (score 7):

That normally means "Call at your earliest convenience."

So basically, now if it's still during office hours, or call first thing.  If he's not available, try again later.  If he's *still* not available, email again and say that you'd try to ring him but was unable to catch him.  He can then either call you when he *is* available (if he has your number, feel free to include it in the email), or can arrange a specific time time with you.